# Flutter: issue with Future which block a function

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, future

I am currently developping a flutter application with Dart. I want to add some local notification when there is something new.

For that I'm using a periodic task with workmanager, which make a http request to check the last "news". The issue here is that the function stop at client.get()

```
Future<List<String>> _grepLastNews() async {
  var client2 = new http.Client();
  debugPrint("here");

  //issue below
  final response =
  await client2.get('http://..../lireLastNews.php').timeout(Duration(seconds: 4));

  client2.close();
  debugPrint("here 2");

  var body;

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     body = jsonDecode(response.body);
  } else {
    return ["0","0"];
  }
  return jsonDecode(body);
}
```

Here you can find the output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgBig.png)

You can see it stop before the second checkpoint... I have tried with and without timeout, with changing the name of the other http client of the application but nothing work. I must add that I have an other http client which work perfectly ( but not in background ^^).
Thanks for helping me

EDIT: I tried with

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2),() => ["0","0"]);
```

but the output is the same so the issue is not with http.get but about the future which I don't know why stop there.

EDIT 2: In fact in an async function I tried

```
    debugPrint("here 2");
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    debugPrint("here 3");
```

and it never go for "here 3".

EDIT 3:
I tried differents variant using    `Future.wait([_grepLastNews()]);` but it don't work: it continue until raising an error because of the null result of _grepLastNews().

Comment: try to wrap your async api call into a `try...catch` block. that should give you more insights on the issue. Add the error to your question, if you need further help. https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: I tried with try{ response =await client2.get(...); } catch(e) {debugPrint(e);} but the output is the same as previously.